# Center of google map changes after placing markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am initializing a google map using a GeoLocation service to set the initial latlng. The map is draggable, and dragging changes the center of the map.

I can place markers from a DB successfully, however doing so always changes the center of the map back to the original latlng (from geolocation).

I would like to be able to drag the map (changing the center), then place the markers, **but leave the center of the map at the location to which it was dragged.**

I'm not sure why running the function to place the markers (even when there are no markers in the DB to place!) always causes the map center to revert to when it was first initialized...

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use setCenter function to change the center after setting up the marker. Something might be resetting the center when you are setting up marker (which is difficult to say without seeing your code), but you can always set the center manually.

```
setCenter(latlng:LatLng|LatLngLiteral)
```

You can use MarkerOptions to set marker to which you can provide Map. While providing the map, just set center of this map.